# Starting a job in a thread reads from queue from other thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a problem that I can't figure out. It might not be easy to explain.

I have a singleton class with this private constructor:

```
private BarcodeMonitor()
{
    processors[Machines.H1] = new BarcodeProcessor { Queue = new BlockingQueue<BarcodeData>("H1") };
    processors[Machines.H2] = new BarcodeProcessor { Queue = new BlockingQueue<BarcodeData>("H2") };
    processors[Machines.M] = new BarcodeProcessor { Queue = new BlockingQueue<BarcodeData>("M") };
    processors[Machines.HP] = new BarcodeProcessor { Queue = new BlockingQueue<BarcodeData>("HP") };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<Machines, BarcodeProcessor> pair in processors)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(t1 => pair.Value.StartProccesingQueue());
        t.Name = pair.Key.ToString() + "Processor";
        t.Start();
        threads.Add(t);
    }
}
```

A new and unique `BlockingQueue` is given to the `BarcodeProcessor` and takes a name.

The `BarcodeMonitor` has this method:

```
public BlockingQueue<BarcodeData> GetQueue(Machines machine)
{
    var processor = processors[machine];
    return processor.Queue;
}
```

so that incoming barcodes are put in the queue of the right machine. This works fine.

The barcodes are dequeued in `StartProccesingQueue()` (of which 4 instances are running). In the dequeue method, I have:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread {0} is taking from queue {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, name));
```

`Dequeue()` uses `Monitor.Wait(_internalQueue)` when the queue is empty. The `Enqueue()` uses `Monitor.PulseAll(_internalQueue)` to continue the waiting dequeue.

What is happening, is that the `StartProccesingQueue()` method takes from other queues, even though it just access that `Queue` property that is assigned with a new `BlockingQueue`. In fact, thus far, I've only seen items from queue "M" being taken, and only the H1 and H2 threads are doing it.

I really don't get why this is happening.

Comment: You are accessing the foreach-iterator variable in a closure. That's dangerous and the behaviour is compiler-dependent. It might be the reason. Simply do a `var value = pair.Value;' and use that in the lambda and see if that helps.

Comment: @Dirk Wow, that did it. All the time it took me to find that out... Post as an answer for the acceptance :)

Comment: It's been answered a couple of times already, it's just a different context. I'll post a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not really sure about this but I think when you do the `pulseAll(_internalQueue)` all waiting threads are noticed that the `_internalQueue` is now ready to be processed, see [MSDN PulseAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulseall(v=vs.110).aspx). 
Maybe try just `pulse(_internalQueue)` this should notify only the Threads waiting for this `_internalQueue`, see [MSDN pulse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I indeed was confused why the original author of the `BlockingQueue` used `PulseAll()`, but in the end, the answer had to do with accessing the foreach variable in a closure. See the first comment to my question.